# Detect youtube video format with jQuery

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api

How can I get the correct format of an `iframe` embedded Youtube video using jQuery?

I need to know if the video is originally (at Youtube) in 3:4 format or 9:16 format or something else.

And I need this in order to remove some black bars from the top and bottom (from my question: [Show Youtube video and thumbnail in correct 9:16 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684503/show-youtube-video-and-thumbnail-in-correct-916-format)) that are added to the video and its thumbnail. If I can find the correct format, I might be able to hide these bars by adjusting the height.

**Update**

I use the plugin [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) for jQuery to play a youtube video by simply having the URL. This is the driving code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  /*Youtube videos*/
  $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    animation_speed: 'fast',
    slideshow: 8000,
    hideflash: true,
    show_title: false,
    changepicturecallback: function(){
      /*At video start do some stuff*/          
    },
    social_tools: false
  });

});
```

That means, I don't myself add and create the video iframe for the youtube film. I don't have much experience with Youtube's API. Is there a straight ahead way to find the original video ratios?

Comment: show us your current codes, especially in YouTube API codes .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get YouTube video aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010495/how-to-get-youtube-video-aspect-ratio)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I find my question a bit different; please wait with closing the question. I tried the best answer to that question you are linking to mplungjan, and it didn't work - please see my comment to that answer. He does though also mention the API, but I'm not sure how to use the API in my situation. @ShivanRaptor, see my update above. How can I use the API method here?

Comment: Please see my new response at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010495/how-to-get-youtube-video-aspect-ratio/15908280#15908280

Comment: Thanks. I will close the question - the answer is on that other page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)