# Make YouTube video background of entire div (onYouTubeIframeAPIReady)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I'm trying to get a YouTube video to load and span the entire with and height of a div (`hero__container--teaser`). I've managed to get the video to load but unsure on how I can make it the div's background?

Here's my  **hero.js**:

```js
      //  Load  IFrame Player API 
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // Creating iframe
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          videoId: 'jagIsKF8oVA',        
          playerVars: {'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0, 'mute' : 1, 'loop': 1, 'rel': 0 },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      //  Calls function
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        // if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
        //   setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
        //   done = true;
        // }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        // player.stopVideo();
      }
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>

  <section id="videoHero" class="hero hero--video">

  <!-- Where I want video to load -->
  <div class="player hero__container--teaser">

  </div>

</section>
```

Idea's?

ANSWER: https://codepen.io/GAUTAMRAJU15/pen/wENdzg
This link contains Answer . IT WRAPS DIV AROUND IFRAME

Comment: Use the [2nd answer solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33300299/1891677). The linked article explains the technique.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I'm not looking to just echo out the video in an <iframe> via hard code. I want to utilize YouTube's API to create the iframe for me and then make it appear within a selected div

Comment: That's great, @Freddy. However, it has nothing to do with the resizing of container technique. Control the ratio of your container `<div>` using the bottom padding percentage technique, make it relative and give the YT API's iframe `position:absolute; width: 100%; left:0; top:0;`.

Comment: If you're loading dynamic videos and w/h ratio might vary, use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010495/how-to-get-youtube-video-aspect-ratio) to retrieve current video's ratio and change the parent's `padding-bottom` dynamically.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu - ah, let me check if I'm doing this correctly - https://jsfiddle.net/2dqw1hc9/4/ - I've tried to play around, can't get the video span the div's height and width.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu also thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180441/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-freddy).